# Manga about a man transported to another world where humans no longer exist, but human hair and such grants power to other races of beings

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

This is a manga that I read quite a while ago and have been wanting to re-read even though it's been completed.

It's a harem isekai about a man that just appears in a different world with two moons. In this world, all humans are gone but elves and other races still exist, trying to find traces of humans because human hair and other bodily substances ;) grant power.

That's the main premise, but there is more information as little as it may be. If you need more info for your search, please comment; I'll reply as fast as I can. Thanks for the help (p.s this is my first time using this website).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, do you recall roughly how many chapters there were?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is ***[Humans are the Strongest Race](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/y4xhmjl/saikyou-no-shuzoku-ga-ningen-datta-ken)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Elf? Dwarf? No! Humans are the strongest!
> I was summoned to a different world where humans are the strongest living beings. In my previous world I was just a normal everyday salaryman, but in this new world, I seem to have become a rare existence.
> I, who have obtained the strongest power through my race, have decided to enjoy this seemingly stress-free life to the fullest.

The MC is isekaied to a world where humans are long extinct, but they're worshipped by other races as an ancient and mighty race, and their body parts, such as a strand of hair, are considered extremely valuable and capable of granting great power.

[image]

[image]